# Want to Decrypt a PDU format SMS Using C# coding

Tags: c#, encryption, pdu

every one i have developed a application in C# for recieving SMS using AT commands. After recieving the Message content is converting in to PDU format. SO, any one can help me how to Convert the PDU formated SMS to normal string.

Thanks in Advance,
Regards
Kalyan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/smspdulib.aspx)

Comment: Orlowski, the link which u have given contains only the description about what is PDU format, and which class in C# handles the SMS parts. I have find just now, a site which gives Complete Decrypting. If u want to see look at [this(http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/samples.htm)]

Comment: The Answer I find out at final is, if we execute this Command before executing the Read command we can read the text msg easily, i.e., AT+CMGF=1, after this command AT+CMGR=<MsgNo>